# Dataframe UDFs for faster performance?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes in Pyspark like this (it may have more companies):

**df1**

```
Company Name              UnderspendAmount 
Pepsi                     2700.00
Pepsi                     1200.00
```

**df2**

```
Company Name              OverspendAmount 
Pepsi                     3600.00
Pepsi                     1400.00
```

So basically the goal is that for the same `Company Name`, I want to be able to match the **maximum** underspend with the **maximum** overspend and the 2nd most with the 2nd most, 3rd most with the 3rd most if that make sense.

The end result after a join something like this:

```
Company Name              OverspendAmount              UnderspendAmount
Pepsi                     3600.00                      2700.00
Pepsi                     1400.00                      1200.00
```

So I have a **very** bruteforce and slow approach for this is which is using `collect`. I am hoping there is a way to solve this using UDFS and `agg`?

This the current approach:

```
for row in df1.select('Company Name').distinct().collect():
   current_company = row['Company Name'] # Get the company name
   df1_sorted_by_desc = df1.orderBy(col('UnderspendAmount').desc()
   df2_sorted_by_desc = df1.orderBy(col('OverspendAmount').desc()
   df1_collected = df1_sorted_by_desc.collect()
   df2_collected = df2_sorted_by_desc.collect()
   for indx in min(df1_collected.count(), df2_collected.count()): # get the min lenght for matching
     matching_row_df1 = df1_collected[indx]
     matching_row_df2 = df2_collected[indx]
     ....
```

SO you get the gist, it is a pretty bad approach and takes a long time to execute. What is the optimal approach for this (and in general)? Is UDF+agg possible for this (and possible extensions to this?)

Answer (score 0):

Use Spark SQL built-in functions, the `rank` windowing function to order the two dataframes according to their respective amounts, and then join the two dataframes on `Company name`+`rank`(use inner/left/right join according to the actual situation ).

```
......
df1 = df1.withColumn('rank', F.expr('rank() over (partition by `Company Name` order by UnderspendAmount desc)'))
df2 = df2.withColumn('rank', F.expr('rank() over (partition by `Company Name` order by OverspendAmount desc)'))
df = df1.join(df2, on=['Company Name', 'rank'], how='inner').drop('rank')
```

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as @过过招, but with Spark API instead of Spark SQL

**ranking for `UnderspendAmount`**

```py
df1 = df1.withColumn('rn', F.rank().over(W.partitionBy('Company').orderBy(F.desc('UnderspendAmount'))))
# +-------+----------------+---+
# |Company|UnderspendAmount| rn|
# +-------+----------------+---+
# |  Pepsi|          2700.0|  1|
# |  Pepsi|          1200.0|  2|
# +-------+----------------+---+
```

**ranking for `OverspendAmount`**

```py
df2 = df2.withColumn('rn', F.rank().over(W.partitionBy('Company').orderBy(F.desc('OverspendAmount'))))
# +-------+---------------+---+
# |Company|OverspendAmount| rn|
# +-------+---------------+---+
# |  Pepsi|         3600.0|  1|
# |  Pepsi|         1400.0|  2|
# +-------+---------------+---+
```

**Join back**

```py
df1.join(df2, on=['Company', 'rn']).orderBy('rn')
# +-------+---+----------------+---------------+
# |Company| rn|UnderspendAmount|OverspendAmount|
# +-------+---+----------------+---------------+
# |  Pepsi|  1|          2700.0|         3600.0|
# |  Pepsi|  2|          1200.0|         1400.0|
# +-------+---+----------------+---------------+
```